# How to call only some files from a folder full of files using python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have many files inside 1 folder.
This is a description of names:

AWA_s1_Fp1_features.mat

AWA_s1_C3_features.mat

AWA_s1_C4_features.mat

AWA_s1_Fp2_features.mat

Rem_s1_Fp1_features.mat

Rem_s1_C3_features.mat

Rem_s1_C4_features.mat

Rem_s1_Fp2_features.mat

SWS_s1_Fp1_features.mat

SWS_s1_C3_features.mat

SWS_s1_C4_features.mat

SWS_s1_Fp2_features.mat

s1 goes from 1 to 38.

So, how can I call them? For example I only want to call the AWA_sx_C3 ones: 
AWA_s1_C3_features.mat, AWA_s2_C3_features.mat ...AWA_s38_C3_features.mat

How can I do it? 
With this code I call all the AWA files (C3, C4, Fp1 and Fp2). But I only want the C3 ones.

```
    read_files = glob.glob('/media/FeaturesX/AWA_s*.mat')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
read_files = glob.glob('/media/FeaturesX/AWA_s*_C3_features.mat')
```

The pattern matching in `glob` is fairly literal.  By putting `_C3_features.mat` after the `*`, we require that part of the string to exist for the match to be valid.